# Verifying if an email contains a s/mime in python

Tags: python, smime

Is it possible, using python without os calls, to detect if an incoming email message is signed ? (Don't care about the certificate validity, I just want to know if the message contains a signed content)

The corresponding openssl command I'd like to reproduce is the following:

`openssl smime -verify -in /tmp/mails/d4fa5d0f-2250-4acd-8d3d-14c4e9743392`

I can run `os.system('openssl smime -verify -in /tmp/mails/d4fa5d0f-2250-4acd-8d3d-14c4e9743392')` but I would like to use a python lib instead if possible.

All the examples I have found implies that I have a public key to decode the certificate, I only want to know if the email contains a signed content or not.

Comment: It is possible without calling `openssl`. Just use a openssl library inside python.

Comment: What about https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

```
import email


msg = email.message_from_file(open('/home/mailuser/testmail.mail'))
if 'signed' in msg.get_content_type():
    <your code here>
```

...works for me